# Sql query for searching values in the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

i've got a problem.
I have a table with these columns:

languageID languageItem

Every row can have only "2" or "3" as languageID and languageItem is always different, but only with the same languageID. For example i can have:

```
2 | header.title
2 | header.description
3 | header.description
3 | header.title
```

The problem is that now the rows which have the languageID as "3" are less than rows which have the languageID as "2" and i need that for each languageID there must be the same languageItem(s). Like:

```
2 | header.title
2 | header.description
2 | header.button
3 | header.title
3 | header.description
```

Is missing header.button for "3"

I want select all rows which the languageID 2 have more and then "copy" them and insert with the languageID 3.

Thanks

EDIT: The rows don't have only these 2 columns, but also others.

Comment: If the table has only two columns (as suggested by the question), then the result is simply a cross product of `languageID` and `languageItem`.  This doesn't seem particularly useful.

Comment: The table has got also other columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by just inserting values that don't exist.  The query looks like:

```
insert into table(languageId, languageItem)
    select 3, languageitem
    from table t
    where languageid = 2 and
          not exists (select 1
                      from table t3
                      where t3.languageid = 3 and t3.languageitem = t.langaugeitem
                     );
```

Comment: can you explain me the "not exists" and the select Xnumber? Thanks

Comment: @user3142019 . . . This is just implementing your logic.  Take all values from the table where language id is 2 and there are no records that already exist for language 3.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO LanguageItems(languageID, languageItem)
SELECT
    3,
    WantedValues.languageItem
FROM
    LanguageItems WantedValues
    LEFT JOIN LanguageItems ExistingValues ON 
            WantedValues.languageItem = ExistingValues.languageItem 
            AND WantedValues.languageID = 2
            AND ExistingValues.languageID = 3
WHERE
    WantedValues.languageID = 2 
    AND ExistingValues.languageID IS NULL
```

Comment: You have `WantedItems.languageId` twice (once in join, once in where), and you have `ExistingValues.languageID` twice, once with NULL, once with 3. I think you need to fix this query

Comment: `WantedItems.LanguageID` in the where clause was incorrect, should have been `WantedValues.LanguageID`. The rest of the query is correct http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9dac7/2

Answer (score 0):

You can use INSERT IGNORE here:

```
insert ignore into mytable(languageId, languageItem)
select 3 as languageId, languageitem from mytable where languageid = 2;
```

(Provided of course there is a unique index on languageId + languageItem.)